# Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Second (I believe; could also be third) time today I'm confronted with this

> Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught IllegalStateException.

with the only option being to disable the plugin.
I don't do that and just restart Android Studio (3.0 Beta 6).

So far, I have yet to encounter any side-effects other than that one-time pop-up, so I guess this could just be related to my accidentally mistyping something (which would still be very strange a reason to fail completely), but ... is there any way to check what happened? Because this error message doesn't say terribly much and even if I couldn't do anything about it, it's not even useful to report something like this.

If it matters, I have recently updated the kotlin plugin (because android studio showed me a pop-up suggesting I should). Of course I also updated my gradle build file so it reads

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
```

However, as I'm only just learning Kotlin, I haven't actually used it long enough to say whether this might have occured if I hadn't updated the Kotlin plugin. So it may or may not be related. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Does something actually break when this error occurs? If nothing breaks, you can basically just close the popup and move on. The plugin has some small problems sometimes, but it always kept working for me after these sort of exceptions.

Comment: There was an error with the plugin repository that caused the wrong version of the plugin to be made available to Android Studio users. Please uninstall and reinstall the plugin, you'll get the correct version now (1.0.5-release-Studio2.2-3).

Comment: @chandrakantsharma that is a very, very old version of the plugin.

Comment: @zsmb13 haven't actually noticed anything - then again, I always pretty immediately restarted AS, just to be sure, so ...

Comment: It is fine.I sometime encounter it when I change the Kotlin code rapidly (I mean really copy&paste,  undo a large code). It is probably the Kotlin plugin have some problem parse your code and index it. It does not matter much (It is only an the IDE plugin, not related to compile). If it brothers you, just restart your IDE and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting these lately, sometimes AS keeps working, sometimes not. The best remedy so far for me is a hit on `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Happy coding.